# how to split in unix using special character

Tags: shell, unix

I have a line like below:

**/home/user/pigscripts/abc.pig**

Can anybody help me in writing a shell script or unix command.

I want to get only abc from above line.
 the out put should give me only
**abc**

Answer (score -1):

```
$ python -c "import os; base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('/home/user/pigscripts/abc.pig')); print base"
pig
```